# ¿Cómo validar con una función todos los datos recibidos por $_POST con empty e isset?

Tags: php, aplicación-web, validación, seguridad

¿Cómo puedo validar todos los datos enviados al servidor por medio de una función que compruebe si existe y no esté vacío, y que me retorne true o false? Son demasiados datos que envía un formulario.

He realizado esta función pero no me funciona en el último valor ingresado.

```php
public function validatePost($array) {
    $error = false;
    foreach($array as $value) {
        if (isset($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $error = true;
        }
    }
    return $error;
}


public function register() {

    if (@$_POST) {

        foreach($_POST as $campo => $valor) {
            $asig = "$".$campo.
            "='".htmlspecialchars($valor, ENT_QUOTES).
            "';";
            eval($asig);
        }
        $array = array($name, $last);
        if ($this - > validatePost($array)) {
            echo "<h3>Todos los datos fueron recibidos</h3>";
        } else {
            echo "<h3>Error:faltaron datos para realizar el registro</h3>";;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que valores envias en el arreglo?

Comment: en $array = array($name,$last); resibe $name=$_POST['name']    $last=$POST['last'] como esta el   foreach($_POST as $campo => $valor) los convierte en $name y $last si necesidad de utlizar $_POST['name'] y $_POST['last']

Comment: Me refiero a que datos envías por POST, coloca el resultado de hacer un print_r a $_POST, print_r($_POST); para ver que datos estan almacenados en el arreglo

Comment: Array
(
    [name] => valentina
    [last] => 
    [phone] => 829837168
    [mail] => valentina0012@hotmail.com
    [username] => valen
    [password] => valentina
    [state] => 1
) //Es el resultado con print_r y estoy ensayando solo con $name y $last

Comment: @FerchoJerez, ¿te ha servido la respuesta de Mariano? ¿Has encontrado una mejor solución? Puede que [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) otro link te ayuden a saber que hacer a continuación.

Comment: Qué hace la @? No lo termino de entender

Answer (score 3):

#### Problema del código:

El problema es que, si el primer parámetro existe, estás asignando `$error=true;`, y no importa si después falta alguno (y estás usando `$error` para indicar si está bien -el nombre confunde).

Por otro lado, es muy peligroso estar usando `eval()` con datos proporcionados por el usuario. Implica un riesgo de seguridad para tu solución.

#### Solución:

Definimos la clase `ParametrosPOST` para procesar todos los parámetros recibidos y luego obtenerlos como `$paramPOST->username` (o el que sea).

Además, `$paramPOST->estanTodosLosParametros` devuelve si se recibieron todos los parámetros deseados del formulario.

**Código:**

```php
class ParametrosPOST
{
    public $estanTodosLosParametros;  // true/false si se enviaron todos
    private $_valores;
    
    
    public function __construct(Array $parametros) {
        $this->estanTodosLosParametros = true;
        
        //verificar que estén todos
        foreach ($parametros as $valor) {
            if (isset($_POST[$valor]) && !empty($_POST[$valor])) {
                $this->_valores[$valor] = $_POST[$valor];
            } else {
                $this->estanTodosLosParametros = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // $paramPOST->nombre
    //   y que devuelva $paramPOST->_valores['nombre']

    public function __get($param){
        return array_key_exists($param, $this->_valores)
            ? $this->_valores[$param]
            : null;
    }
    
    public function __set($param, $valor){
        return $this->_valores[$param] = $valor;
    }
    
}
```

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```php
$paramPOST = new ParametrosPOST([  // listar todos
    'name','last','phone',
    'username','mail','password',
    'state'
    ]);

if ($paramPOST->estanTodosLosParametros) {
    echo "
        <h3>Todos los datos fueron recibidos</h3>
        <p>Nombre: $paramPOST->name</p>
        <p>Tel: $paramPOST->phone</p>
        ";
} else {
    echo "<h3>Error: faltaron datos para realizar el registro</h3>";;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo en ideone.com](http://ideone.com/3dpili)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
class Myclass
{
  /* @var Array **/
  private $datos_formulario;

  // Si se hace el objeto sin enviar datos, que sea array vacio por defecto
  public function__construct( $datos_formulario = array())
  {
    $this->datos_formulario = $datos_formulario;
  }

  public function evaluarValores()
  {  
    foreach( $this->datos_formulario as $value)
    {
      // Si no existe o esta vacio 
      if (! isset($value) or empty ($value))
      {
        return false;
      }

    }
    // Si nunca entra al if, entonces todo bien
    return true;
  }

}
```

Y para alicarlo:

```
// En realidad puedes enviar cualquier array
$my_class = new Miclass($_POST);

$my_class -> evaluarValores();
```

Esto es sólo un ejemplo y no sé qué tan práctico pueda ser para ti el crear un atributo y pasar su valor por constructor. Una alternativa es pasar el array Post (o el que quieras) por parámetro:

```
public function evaluarValores( $array_valores)
```