# Amigos Tengo ese codigo y me provoca este error

Tags: php

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el codigo como texto, no como imagen y señala cual es el error.

Comment: Amigo soy nuevo aun no se bien como usar el sitio estoy trabajndo en ello y el error me dice que Undefined index: buscar in en la linea de codigo 10

Comment: agradezco la paciencia

Comment: Si mejora su pregunta muchos lo ayudaremos, nosotros necesitamos el codigo como texto ya que lo queremos probar, transcribir codigo de una imagen es cansado, ademas de que podemos comenter errores de tipeo. si eres nuevo te recomiendo pasar el [tour] y leer [ask]

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigo lo hare

Comment: Lo mismo que los compañeros, hace falta más información, sobretodo la parte del código. Pero parece por el error que te da, que no encuentra una posición del array que el bucle intenta o bien te está llegando el array sin datos. saludos

Comment: Como te dicen los otros: copia el mensaje de error y el código en formato de texto en lugar de como imágenes. Eso hace que se indexe mejor, sea más fácil de encontrar y ayudarte. Lee [ask] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), y luego edita tu pregunta. Aparte de eso, algunos comentarios sobre las imágenes: tu código usa métodos deprecados e inseguros, puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL, y parece compartir información personal.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo validar con una función todos los datos recibidos por $\_POST con empty e isset?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21223/c%c3%b3mo-validar-con-una-funci%c3%b3n-todos-los-datos-recibidos-por-post-con-empty-e-i)

Answer (score 1):

El error te indica que estas intentando acceder a un indice inexistente en un array. En éste casi `$_POST['buscar']` no existe.

Haz un debug de *post* para saber que contiene:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Cómo todo tu código posterior depende de ese valor que no te está llegando, no vas a poder mostrar nada, deberías proveer un mensaje de error para el usuario que hace la búsqueda, tanto para evitar este tipo de errores como para el caso de que no recuperes datos al completar la busqueda. Yo en todo caso para el error de que no existe esa posición en *post* generaría un log de uso interno y un mensaje genérico para el usuario.

```
$err = 'No existen datos para la búsqueda actual';
$nombre = (isset($_POST['buscar']))
    ? $_POST['buscar']
    : null;


if ($nombre) {

    //Aquí tu consulta a la BD
    //

    //Comprobar que tienes datos a mostrar
    //
    //Si hay datos -> Sigues con tu código
    //
    //Si NO hay datos:
    // -> Puedes volver a la vista anterior, supongo que con el formulario de busqueda
    // -> Mostrar mensaje de error al usuario (contenido de $err)

} else {

    //Generar log de errores de la aplicación (uso interno)
    //

    //Mostrar mensaje de error al usuario (contenido de $err)
    //
}
```

Hay que poner el código en las preguntas y lo más completo posible para que se pueda reproducir el error a ser posible y dar la mejor solución, te respondí con lo que tenía.

Ya dí una respuesta a éste tipo de error en otra pregunta, puedes consultarla [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128888).

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Practicare y les cuento como me va...

Comment: probe el codigo "elimina el error pero al buscar no me muestra nada ??

Comment: Si usas el código que te puse arriba, tal cual, no hace nada. Vas a tener en la variable **$nombre** el contenido de **$_POST['buscar']** o un **null**. Puedes hacer una prueba poniendo **echo $nombre;** dentro del **if** y un **echo $err;** en el bloque **else**, así sabrás donde entra.

Answer (score 0):

Usando:

```
$Nombre = $_POST['buscar'];
```

Cuando tu página recarga por primera vez, busca el valor que contiene ese indice en el Array, lógicamente no lo encuentra ya que el array no tiene esa posición creada aun y además no contiene ningún valor.

La solución es que ejecute esa linea y la consulta a la BD, SI existe el valor en ese indice del ARRAY. Esto lo hacemos con el siguiente código:

```
if(isset($_POST['buscar'])){
//Consulta SQL
}
```

De esta forma el código solo se ejecutara una vez que exista ese indice en el Array y no en la carga de la pagina como ocurre en tu ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias lo pondre en practica